# How to make an online PHP point of sale (POS) system have offline capability?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have been working on a POS system in PHP/MySQL and if the customers internet goes down they lose all ability to sell their products.

I will only need basic functionality while in "offline mode" for example selling a product I just need to record the price/qty and product id.

It is possible for me to use the latest browsers so I have been researching HTML5 localStorage, which can store data into the browser session which will work fine if I use AJAX to record the transactions.

But I am not sure exactly how to check that the internet has gone down, how to ensure the client can still see the webpage without getting an error/no connection screen, and how to implement the localStorage functionality to overwrite the regular functionality.

If you can help or have a better way of dealing with this that will be excellent!

Side note: I am considering moving to use this open source point of sale if that helps - http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensourcepos/?source=directory

Thanks

EDIT: Also the search function is used to find all products and is called using AJAX. Is there a way to store the product list (generated from MySQL) locally as well. I could populate a list of all products into the html but if the page is refreshed it will be lost.

Comment: So just to be clear, the webserver is running on the customers network?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: What you need is an offline web app. If you set it up properly, it will download javascript code and other assets to a browser, and run them from there. By changing the manfest the browser will update application files automatically when on line. Your Javascript can look for a connection and update data files or use cached versions as it needs. You can find a tuturial [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Comment: Yes the web server is run from the customers network. Thanks HMR and Mike with your two comments put together I might be able to work out a solution